# check for multiple roles

Tags: 6

This code I use when checking if user has a role

```
if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles)))
```

How to check for multiple roles? I tried something like this

```
if (!in_array('administrator', 'operator',  array_values($user->roles))
```

I made it work like this

```
if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles)) && in_array('operator', array_values($user->roles)))
```

but there must be some less code solution.
but it is not working. Thank you.

Comment: If you fancy a sql solution then you could try some of things here,https://www.drupal.org/node/7614#comment-298858

Comment: @pal4life I would prefer php solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at PHP's array_diff() function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

This will compare an array of the roles you're checking for against the array of the user's roles, and return an array containing the leftovers.

```
<?php
$roles_to_check_for = array('administrator', 'operator');
$users_roles = array_values($user->roles);

if (array_diff($roles_to_check_for, $users_roles)) {
  // User does not have all of the $roles_to_check_for.
}
else {
  // User has all of the $roles_to_check_for.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found from http://drupal-howtos.blogspot.com/. I do not have a drupal 6 setup so could not verify but the solution seems reasonable. Try the foreach part and see if it helps.

```
<?php
  global $user;

  // You can traverse through the array
  // and check if user has the role you want
  foreach($user->roles as $rid => $role){
    if($role == "role_i_want"){
      // Do something
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for Drupal 8.

```
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

     /**
     * Utility function that checks for single or multiple roles.
     *
     * @param string or array $roles
     *   The role(s) to check.
     *
     * @param AccountInterface $account
     *   The user to check
     *
     * @return bool
     *   Whether the account has the role(s)
     *
     */
    
    function _user_has_roles($roles, AccountInterface $account) {
        // checks if the account has role(s)
        $roles = is_array($roles) ? $roles : [$roles];
        return !!count(array_intersect($roles, array_values($account->getRoles()));
    };
```

For example:

```
$isGeek = _user_has_roles(['maker', 'baker'], \Drupal::currentUser());
$isBaker = _user_has_roles('baker', \Drupal::currentUser());
```